# Pyspark - IndentationError: expected an indented block using Cloudera Virtual Machine

Tags: loops, pyspark, indentation

I'm using the terminal under the Cloudera Virtual Machine Quickstart - 5.13.0-0-virtualbox.

```
employeeinfo = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM EmployeeTab")
for row in employeeinfo.collect():
... print(row)
```

And I get this error:

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

And I think I am putting the correct spaces after the loop for as you can see on the following image:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
employeeinfo = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM EmployeeTab")
for row in employeeinfo.collect():
...     print(row)
```

put 4 spaces after `...`